# Ошибка после релиза альфа версии

Tags: java, android

Это злой рок какой то, после того как я выложил свое приложение в альфа тестирование понеслись ошибки, причем не только в релиз версии а так же и в дебаг версии, при том что странно на эмуляторе запускается а на телефоне приложение вылетает, хотя до этого все работало. И программный код я не трогал. Складывается впечатление что целиком программирование под андроид это велосипед какойто=(( Вобщем вот отрезок кода:

```
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {                                     
        network = 1;                                                                            
    } else {                                                                                    
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);                            
        builder.setTitle("Предупреждение")                                                      
                .setMessage("Для корректной работы приложения включите Интернет")               // и текстом
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                //
                    @Override

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                                      
                        Intent gpsNetworkIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);         // открываем окно настроек
                        startActivity(gpsNetworkIntent);                                        
                    }                                                                                   
                })                                                                          
                .setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();                                                   
        alert.show();                                                                           
    }
}
```

Вот логи ошибки:

```
: Activity tat.example.ildar.seer.Main_Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{35b687a2 V.E..... R....... 0,0-694,383} that was originally added here
                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:530)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:287)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
                     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:325)
                     at tat.example.ildar.seer.Main_Activity.onCreate(Main_Activity.java:191)
                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
D/InputMethodManager: windowDismissed mLockisused = false
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity tat.example.ildar.seer.Main_Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5574c33 V.E..... R....... 0,0-694,383} that was originally added here
                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:530)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:287)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
                     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:325)
                     at tat.example.ildar.seer.Main_Activity.onCreate(Main_Activity.java:217)
                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

(Main_Activity.java:217) указывает на alert.show();

выше на 191 строке такой же кусок кода и на него тоже логи ссылаются. Что здесь не так? и почему до того как я создал релиз версию, все работало как часы и на эмуляторе и в телефоне(((((

Comment: У вас падает или просто в логах ругается? Если второе, то можно просто забить. Если первое, то попробуйте вместо ` dialog.cancel();` использовать ` dialog.dismiss();`

Comment: Крошится. Все таки пока не опубликуешь вопрос ответ не найдется, как только опубликовал сразу эту проблему решил, из onCreate() перенес в onResume, теперь вылазиет ошибка с AsyncTask, чувствую я что что то не так пошл, ведь этих ошибок не было, все запускалось, в чем может быть причина я уже не знаю что думать...

Comment: Ну, собственно да - из onCreate диалог показывать - не лучшая идея) Напишите об этом в ответ и задавайте новый вопрос по AsyncTask - что-нибудь подскажем)

Answer (score 1):

Все таки пока не опубликуешь вопрос ответ не найдется, как только опубликовал сразу эту проблему решил, из onCreate() перенес в onResume, и все заработало.