# Ошибка в AsyncTask()

Tags: java, android, okhttp, зависимости

Логи:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: tat.example.ildar.seer, PID: 17683
        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokio/Buffer;
            at okhttp3.ResponseBody.create(ResponseBody.java:208)
            at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:48)
            at okhttp3.internal.Util.immutableList(Util.java:187)
            at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<clinit>(OkHttpClient.java:122)
            at tat.example.ildar.seer.Main_Activity$Regphp.doInBackground(Main_Activity.java:243)
            at tat.example.ildar.seer.Main_Activity$Regphp.doInBackground(Main_Activity.java:240)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "okio.Buffer" on path: DexPathList[[
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-24.2.1_921263f425e80c99f3a405d276c705f3df584449-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-okhttp-3.6.0_27506a713ba55ebb67789dc1f499cd6c909a78f4-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_e31882dafd2edb2910271ed3e857ee54d73cdcc6-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_d0da5686ba7c1ce3ea5c4220100e850658c94309-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_ad845bc93a84a324ba5f9eba1bfb6c7887bc86db-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_a09c4788066e9c6f2c59f5f4e39634ab15ce12ff-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_6f30e1ee9d9653acc66256d266351779c810a4df-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-tasks-9.6.1_5f4a68b5294ff8c54e09f704b6a9d515d9e761b4-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-maps-9.6.1_3280708189ffe5997521fbbf87bf80bbc49189a2-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-basement-9.6.1_486175a14c2eff04778956c8bad8fbf498bf1903-classes.dex", 
            dex file "/data/data/tat.example.ildar.seer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-base-9.6.1_78892452a35c73124774018df7422a21aad72209-classes.dex"
            ...
```

**Код Regphp:**

```
class Regphp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {                                           
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {                                           
        OkHttpClient clientReg = new OkHttpClient();                                            

        RequestBody formBodyReg = new FormBody.Builder()                                       
                .add("reg_id", numReg)
                .add("prog_vers", progVers)
                .build();
        Request requestReg = new Request.Builder()                                              
                .url("http://***-***-**-***.***.***.regruhosting.ru/reg.php")                    
                .post(formBodyReg)
                .build();
        try {
            Response responseReg = clientReg.newCall(requestReg).execute();                     
            if (!responseReg.isSuccessful())
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + responseReg);
            body = responseReg.body().string();                                                 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return body;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJsonReg) {                                          
        super.onPostExecute(strJsonReg);
        try {
            JSONArray ip_connect = new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(strJsonReg));                 
            ip_adress = new String[ip_connect.length()];                                        
            for (int i = 0; i < ip_connect.length(); i++) {                                     
                JSONObject ip = ip_connect.getJSONObject(i);                                 
                ip_adress[i] = ip.getString("ip");                                          
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Как писал в [прошлом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/647599/205238), до этого все запускалось и работало, после релиза перестало работать и в дебаг и в релиз версии, может ли это быть связано с переименованием пакета? Хотя если бы дело было в это то на эмуляторе бы тоже не запускался.

240 строка это соответственно 1-ая по счету строка в отрезке кода.

`Ip` адрес в `url` закрыл звездочками на всякий случай. В программном коде там все норм.

**Код build.gradle(Module: app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tat.example.ildar.seer"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 3
        versionName "0.25"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Частично ошибка ушла, в gradle было 
compile files('libs/okhttp-3.6.0.jar') поменял на compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0', теперь же на эмуляторе и в режиме отладки приложение запускается, а при генерации apk файла выдает ошибку: ZipException: duplicate entry: okhttp3/Address.class. Палка о двух концах, как мне подрубить эту библиотеку что бы не было ни каких ошибок?

Comment: Либо удалите *okhttp-3.6.0.jar* из папки *libs*, либо строку`compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'`
Отключите InstantRun, сделайте очистку проекта, удалите приложение с устройства.
Затем пробуйте собрать.

Comment: ...а также я не совсем понимаю зачем вам нужен `AsyncTask` если `okhttp` **поддерживает асинхронные запросы**

Comment: Да спасибо проблема в этом была, просто я все делал по готовым примерам,где то указывалось что нужно добавить .jar в папку libs где то говорилось что нужно добавить только строку gradle. Вот и получилось у меня двойное включение библиотеки OKHTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Это не является полным решением данной проблемы, но это альтернатива неправильному построению логики запроса.

```
public class NetworkManager{
    private static NetworkManager instance;
    private static OkHttpClient client;

    public static NetworkManager open() {
        if (instance == null){
            synchronized (NetworkManager.class){
                if (instance == null){
                    instance = new NetworkManager();
                    client = new OkHttpClient();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private void callServerApi(Request request, Callback callback){
        client.newCall(requestReg).enqueue(callback);
    }

    public void cancel(Object tag) {
        for (Call call : client.dispatcher().queuedCalls()) {
            if ((call.request().tag()).equals(tag)) call.cancel();
        }
        for (Call call : client.dispatcher().runningCalls()) {
            if ((call.request().tag()).equals(tag)) call.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Вызов `Api`:

```
RequestBody formBodyReg = new FormBody.Builder()                                       
        .add("reg_id", numReg)
        .add("prog_vers", progVers)
        .build();
Request requestReg = new Request.Builder()                                              
        .url("http://***-***-**-***.***.***.regruhosting.ru/reg.php")
        .tag(/*принимает Object*/)/*опциональный параметр, 
необходим для использования метода cancel*/
        .post(formBodyReg)
        .build();

Callback callback = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!responseReg.isSuccessful()){
                Log.e("callServerApi", "Unexpected code " + response);
                return;
            }
            String strJsonReg = response.body().string();
            try {
                JSONArray ip_connect = new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(strJsonReg));                 
                ip_adress = new String[ip_connect.length()];                                        
                for (int i = 0; i < ip_connect.length(); i++) {                                     
                    JSONObject ip = ip_connect.getJSONObject(i);                                 
                    ip_adress[i] = ip.getString("ip");                                          
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

NetworkManager.open().callServerApi(requestReg, callback);
```

Comment: AsyncTask я вызываю судя по примерам других, везде вроде написано что нужно создавать отдельный поток и в нем уже производить коннект. Поэтому я тоже так же поступил. Но учту ваше замечание и переработаю код. Спасибо за подсказку!